# Inserting an array into mysql with Python

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, insert

I am building this array with 40k entries.

```
array = [(value1, value2, value3),(value1, value2, value3),(value1, value2, value3) .... ]
```

Is it possible to insert this into mysql in python something like:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT IGNORE into %s VALUES *array here*''' % (table_name, array))
```

I am having trouble passing the array variable into mysql correctly.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is a solution to a similar problem already asked, hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612933/insert-array-of-values-into-a-database-using-sql-query

Comment: It could be good to check the max size for your server as well. You could do that with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do it with executemany:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT IGNORE into %s VALUES(%s, %s, %s)'%table_name, sql_data)
```

Note: you shouldn't use `%` to pass values to the database, instead you need to pass them in the second parameter of `execute`/`executemany`. i used `%` for the table name because the first parameter is the prepared query string.

Comment: You are welcome, take a look at the note, i edited my answer.

Comment: i meant to update yesterday: 
cursor.executemany('''INSERT IGNORE INTO %s (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s)''' % table_name, (array))

Answer (score 0):

This is Use for me try it.

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="test"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
print("Insert Process... Please Wait...")
for r in range(1,tdrows+1):
    a = []
    for c in range(1,tdcols+1):
        a.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr["+str(r)+"]/td["+str(c)+"]").text)
    sql = "INSERT IGNORE into test_table(id,fname,lname) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    val = (a)
    mycursor.execute(sql,val)
    mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "Record Inserted.")
```